# 0 Accuracy for federated training

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to implement a simple binary classifier for the [KDD](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hassan06/nslkdd/code) dataset using Tensorflow's federated learning framework.
Following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) tutorial what i have done so far is :

1. implemented a classical centralized model(outside of tff) achieving convergence and accurate results
2. Tried to integrate this approach wthin the Federated framework as seen below :

## Functions

```
def make_federated_data(client_data, client_ids):
  return [
      preprocess(client_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x))
      for x in client_ids]

def create_keras_model():
  return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(41,)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(82, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(41, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid')])


def model_fn():
  # We _must_ create a new model here, and _not_ capture it from an external
  # scope. TFF will call this within different graph contexts.
  keras_model = create_keras_model()
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec=preprocessed_example_dataset.element_spec,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])

def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(client_id):
      dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_set.to_dict("list"))
      return dataset
    
    
def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn_2(client_id):
      dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test.to_dict("list"))
      return dataset
    def preprocess(dataset):

def preprocess(dataset):
  def batch_format_fn(element):
    """converting each sample to an `OrderedDict` and then formatting it"""
    
    return collections.OrderedDict(
          x =  tf.reshape(tf.concat([element[i] for i in element.keys() if i!='class'],0), [-1, 41]) ,
        y = tf.reshape(element['class'], [-1, 1]))

  return dataset.repeat(5).shuffle(100, seed=1).batch(  # Repeat = number of rounds
      12).map(batch_format_fn).prefetch(10)
```

## Main

```
    # train_Set and test_Set are dataframes(scaled) with 41 features 
#and 1 label
    #adding client number to each sample
n_clients = 10
train_set['id'] = np.random.randint(0, n_clients ,train_set.shape[0])
test_set['id'] = np.random.randint(0, n_clients , test_set.shape[0])
# DataFrame  conversion
    train_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_tf_fn(
            client_ids = list(client_ids),
            serializable_dataset_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn
        )
    
    test_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_tf_fn(
            client_ids = list(client_ids),
            serializable_dataset_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn_2
        )

    # Sampling for tff
    example_dataset = train_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(
                 train_data.client_ids[0])
    preprocessed_example_dataset = preprocess(example_dataset)
    iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
        model_fn,
        client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
        server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001))

     federated_train_data = make_federated_data(train_data, train_data.client_ids)
```

Where we have 41 features and a label.I have also checked the labels here and they correctly are between 0 and 1.
At this point federated data signature is :

```
<PrefetchDataset element_spec=OrderedDict([('x', TensorSpec(shape=(None, 41), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)), ('y', TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))])>,
 <PrefetchDataset element_spec=OrderedDict([('x', TensorSpec(shape=(None, 41), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)), ('y', TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))])>,
         ...
```

Finally,

```
state = iterative_process.initialize()
NUM_ROUNDS = 10
for round_num in range(0, NUM_ROUNDS):
  state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
  print('round {:2d}, metrics={}'.format(round_num, metrics))
```

The result of the loop above is 0.0 accuracy for each iteration and  loss that is not really changing.
The problem is probably related to the model and the training process since i think the dataset is in correct format but i can't figure out what it is.
The results mentioned probably indicate that the model is not training at all and also that it outputs something completely different from (0,1).
It is also noted that the state(model's weights) do change after each iteration.
Any ideas?